# Embedded Linux - change vertical and horizontal sync signals

Tags: android, embedded-linux

I would like to know how to change the Vertical and Horizontal Sync signal on an embedded Linux device.

1. What are source files that I need to modify, and where in the SDK
   can I find these files?
2. How can I create a loadable module?
3. Do I have to cross-compile the code? If so what is the command set?

**Development Hardware Platforms**
• TI Sitara am335x Starter kit
• Atmel SAMA5D31-EK evaluation board

Both have Android JB loaded

**Development Software Platform**
• Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
• Windows 7 host with a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on VirtualBox

**Hardware platform**: TI Sitara SK

1. LCD controller is initialized in [board-am335xevm.c](http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/android/f/509/t/142583.aspx) file. lcdc_init() is the function call.
2. It appears that [da8xx-fb.c][2] is extensively used to drive the LCD controller but have not been able to identify the flow

Any suggestion to identify the LCD controller software follow is greatly appreciated

Thank you advance

**Update**

Following link has some great idea to achieve the above.

- [HDMI resolution change](http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/android/f/509/t/142583.aspx)

Comment: First you need to identify the video hardware and driver in use, then you can start to determine if this is supportable as a command line option, by modifying the code, or at all.  Also consider if the new vales will work with the display.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Thank you for the feedback. I have added few comments from todays research.